# Input to ChatPromptTemplate is missing variables {'input', 'agent_scratchpad'}. Expected: ['agent_scratchpad', 'input']

Tags: python, langchain, azure-openai

This code gives me an weird error:

```
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableLambda, RunnablePassthrough

def create_weaviate_new_RAG(client, embeddings, llm, class_name_rich, class_properties_rich, class_text_key):
    
    vector_store = Weaviate(client=client,
            index_name=class_name_rich,
            text_key=class_text_key,
            embedding=embeddings,
            attributes=class_properties_rich,
            #by_text=False,
        )

    retriever=vector_store.as_retriever(
                                search_type= "mmr", 
                                search_kwargs={
                                    "k": 4,
                                    "fetch_k": 20,
                                }
                            )

    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
        [
            ("system", "You are a helpful assistant who retrieves information from documents"),
            ("user", "{input}"),
            MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="agent_scratchpad"),
        ]
    )

    rag_pipe = (
        {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
        | prompt
        | llm
        | StrOutputParser()
    )

    return rag_pipe

rag_pipe = create_weaviate_new_RAG(client, embeddings, llm_chat, class_name, ["chunk_id", "doc_name", "doc_path"], "chunk_text")
text = "what is ai policy?"
rag_pipe.invoke(text)
```

Gives me this error:

```
"Input to ChatPromptTemplate is missing variables {'input', 'agent_scratchpad'}.  Expected: ['agent_scratchpad', 'input'] Received: ['context', 'question']"
```

I am using openai==1.7.0 and langchain==0.1.0

This inly started the appear after adding the new rag code from langchain.

Can someone help?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

"Context" and "question" are not mentioned in your prompt as placeholder.

Comment: Please, [edit] and try for [answer], provide more details and describe the effect of what you propose and why it helps to solve the problem. Consider taking the [tour].